# LSYNC don't work when a destination host is unavailable

Tags: lsyncd

Is it possible that lsyncd keeps working when a destination node is unavailable on the network?  I need to sync folders on different servers, but these servers are in an Azure Availability set (autoscale ec2 on AWS), so they can be turned on or off according to the load on my application and lsyncd.

I cannot use a file share for these folders because there are a lot of micro-files.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://axkibe.github.io/lsyncd/manual/config/file/

According to the manual, you can start with 'insist' to allow lsyncd to startup without all of the destinations being available

Comment: It's  what I wanted to find. Really appreciate the solution. I created a script to update the network targets on my Lsyncd nodes when they detect that a node was turned off.